# Probability of having outcome of no overlap?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian

I’m currently having problems understanding how one would calculate the probability (expected value) of having an outcome of no overlap.

1. For instance, how would one calculate the probability of the probability of there being no overlap of birthdays given there is a sample of 100 days, 365 days in a year, and each day has an equal probability of being a birthday of someone.
2. Then taking (1) into consideration, how would I calculate the expected number of distinct birthdays?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What are stuck on exactly? It seems like you could calculate the number of different ways that you could have 100 people/birthdays. You could calculate out of that how many different scenarios feature no one having the same birthday. You could also use that method to figure out for each state how many distinct birthdays there are. A few ways to look at it might be that if everyone is born on January first then there is overlap and one distinct birthday. Now if 99 people are born on January 1 and one person is born on January 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $i=1,2,\dots,365$ let $X_i$ be the random variable whose value is $1$ if at least one person is born on day $i$ and $0$ otherwise, and let $$X=\sum_{i=1}^{365}X_i.$$  Then we want $$E(X)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{365}X_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{365}E(X_i)=365\left(1-\left(364\over365\right)^{100}\right)\approx87.575518$$