# Number of unique elements in new set

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Suppose that we have a set with n elements. Choose at random with replacement any n elements. I.e create new empty set and n times add to this set element from old set (there can be repetitions). How asymptotically many unique elements are there in new set?
Any hints?

Comment: Sounds like the same problem as this [birthday problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331448/probability-of-having-outcome-of-no-overlap/3331470#3331470)

Comment: If you have a set with $n$ elements, and you choose at random "any" $n$ of the elements, you will be (non-randomly) choosing all of the elements.

Comment: @Michael there can be repetitions. It's choosing with replacement.

Comment: @MattSamuel : How do you know that? Is it the case Matt Samuel = friendlyuser?

Comment: @Michael i edited my question

Comment: @Michael it says it right in the post. Parentheses, end of second sentence.

Comment: Well, obviously any number of elements from $1$ to $n$ is possible.  Maybe you are asking about the _expected_ number of elements, as a function of $n$ when $n$ gets large?

Comment: @EricWofsey word asymptotically means the same? Am i right or not?

Comment: @MattSamuel : In the original form, the question talked about having a set with $n$ elements, choosing "any" $n$ of these elements, and that creates a "new empty set..." I agree that what would remain (after taking everything out) is an "empty set" $\phi$ but I don't know what a "new" empty set would mean, ($\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$?) so I couldn't follow to the end of the paragraph getting to the parentheses you state. In retrospect indeed the word "repetition" was there at the last part of the original post which could mean sampling with replacement.

Comment: Asymptotically means you're talking about some kind of limit as $n$ gets large.  It doesn't necessarily mean you're talking about the expected value though.

Comment: @EricWofsey got it. I'm asking about limit, not expected value

Comment: Limit of _what_?

Comment: @Michael i don't understand how did you get first formula

Comment: @friendlyuser : Let $U$ be the number of unique elements chosen and write $U=C_1 + C_2 + ... + C_n$ where $C_i$ is 0/1 depending on if object $i$ was chosen. I deleted the answer as you were asking only for a hint and I wonder if this is a homework problem; I did not recognize it as such because the original wording was unusual. I am also assuming the question wants an average (as Eric suggests +1) even though you say it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you are asking, but I think it is this.  We sample a set of $n$ elements uniformly at random, with replacement, $n$ times.  What is the expected number of distinct elements in the sample?  Give an asymptotic value as $n\to\infty.$

For $i=1,2,\dots,n$ let $X_i$ be a random variable whose value is $1$ if element $i$ appears in the sample and $0$ otherwise, and let $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.  Then we want $$E(X)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i)=n\left(1-\left({n-1\over n}\right)^n\right)\sim n\left(1-\frac1e\right)$$ as $n\to\infty$.